# SQLTableDependency no funciona luego de Restaurar la Base de Datos

Tags: c#, sql-server, consola, sqltabledependency

Estimados estuve practicando la recepción de notificaciones de cambios en las Tablas con SQLTableDependency en un ambiente de testing. No tuve ningún problema, pero luego al llevar la base de datos a un ambiente de producción (Resguardo y luego Restaurar) ya no funcionó mas.

Vi que me vuelve a regenerar los SQLTableDependency's Objects, pero igualmente no recibo las notificaciones.

En la documentación habla que:

> "Database Backup and Restore: restoring SqlTableDependency's db
>   objects, it does not work."

Y al parecer esta allí el problema.

También probé sin resultados positivos:

- Adjuntando la Base de Datos.
- Eliminando manualmente los SQLTableDependency's Objects

El Codigo utilizado es:

```
    class Program
{
    private static string _con = "Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Dependency;User ID=Usuario;Password=XXXXXXXX";
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var dep = new SqlTableDependency<Spoolers>(_con, tableName: "Spoolers"))
        {
            dep.OnChanged += Changed;
            dep.OnError += Error;
            dep.OnStatusChanged += OnStatusChanged;
            dep.TraceLevel = TraceLevel.Verbose;
            dep.TraceListener = new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out);
            dep.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Press a key to exit");
            Console.ReadKey();

            dep.Stop();
        }            
    }

    static void OnStatusChanged(object sender, StatusChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
    }

    public static void Changed(object sender, RecordChangedEventArgs<Spoolers> e)
    {
        var changedEntity = e.Entity;

        Console.WriteLine("DML operation: " + e.ChangeType);
        Console.WriteLine("ID: " + changedEntity.Id_Spooler);
        Console.WriteLine("Id_Estado_Spooler: " + changedEntity.Id_Estado_Spooler);
        Console.WriteLine("Fecha_Hora_Estado_Spooler: " + changedEntity.Fecha_Hora_Estado_Spooler.ToShortTimeString());
    }
    public static void Error(object sender, ErrorEventArgs e)
    {
        Exception ex = e.Error;
        throw ex;        
    }
}
```

¿Hay alguna forma de "reconectar" el programa con los SQLTableDependency's Objects creados?. Los mismos tienen una nomenclatura común.

Comment: Verifica si en la base de datos está activa la opción : "ALTER DATABASE nombreBaseDatos SET ENABLE_BROKER;"

Comment: Luis, buenas. Si está configurado esa opción en la base de datos. Ademas la librería no te permite realizar la conexión si no tienes configurado dicho parámetro. Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Es la misma versión de SQL Server el de producción y el de prueba?

Comment: Estimado Si es la misma versión, 11.0.2100.60. Lo que probé ahora es que restaurando en el mismo server no tengo problemas, si funciona.